# Удаление постов и отображение картинок fotorama-widget в блоге- как решить?

Tags: yii2, url

[image: 1]Если открывать пост в админ.панели admin.site.com/blog/blog/view?id=2#1 - то картинки видно, прокрутка fotorama-widget есть, но на fronted ничего нет.И они не удаляются, как и посты. Из запросов видно, что в (blog/blog/index) запрос идет, а не в blog/image-delete как ожидается. Но что там конкретно менять нужно в url-manager? И в каком именно url-managere? D:\sites\site\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\urlmanager или main.php ?(D:\sites\site\yii2\frontend\config)

[image: 2]

main.php

```html
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log','debug'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'modules'=>[
    'debug'=>[
        'class'=>'yii2\debug\Module'
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
             'blog/<url>'=>'blog/one',
             'blog'=>'blog/index'
            ],
        ],
     ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления картинок нужно добавить в form.php "'pluginOptions'    `blog/blog/image-delete`